# DoubleClickHandler and mapwidget - gwt

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I am using gwt 2.4 and the latest gwt-maps3 wrapper for google maps library. I want to add a double click handler in the mapwidget and get the coordinates (LatLng) of the double clicked spot. I noticed that i don't have all the methods from the API available (click handlers and many others methods are not available ). Any idea?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the available functions with your implementation of "double-click". You need to wrap the JS function using GWT's JSNI.

Take a closer look at the source code of gwt-maps3. You can compare the native Map (class) API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

with the GWT corresponding classes:

- [MapImpl.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/maps/client/impl/MapImpl.java)
- [Map.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/maps/client/Map.java)

More about events you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)